# How do you get this bifurcation diagram of this 2D discrete time model?

Tags: function

I want to replicate the results of "Chaos in Duopoly Pricing" by T. Puu, which can be found here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/096007799190045B#section-cited-by. The model is
[image]
and here's Figure 3 in the paper:
[image]
But for some reason, I can't replicate the result of this rather simple model. My result is
[image]
which is totally different from Figure 3.
Can someone please help? Any program is welcomed (I'm using E&F Chaos).